# Check if node exist in document with XSLT

Tags: xslt

I'm transforming one XML file to another XML format.

Here is sample source file:

```
<xml>
     <title>Pride and Prejudice</title>
     <subtitle>Love Novel</subtitle>
</xml>
```

And here is xsl file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="ISO-8859-1"?>
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0"
            xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">

<xsl:template match="/">
    <Product>
        <xsl:apply-templates/>
    </Product>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="title">
    <TitleDetail>
        <TitleType>01</TitleType>
        <TitleElement>
            <TitleElementLevel>01</TitleElementLevel>
            <TitleText><xsl:value-of select="current()"/></TitleText>
             <!--Here Problem!!!-->
            <xsl:if test="subtitle"> 
                <Subtitle>123</Subtitle>
            </xsl:if>
        </TitleElement>
    </TitleDetail>
</xsl:template>
```

Idea is that if source file contains subtitle tag I need to insert  "Subtitle"  node to the "TitleDetail", but 'if' condition returns false. How to check if source file has subtitle information?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would define another template

```
<xsl:template match="subtitle">
  <Subtitle><xsl:value-of select="."/></Subtitle>
</xsl:template>
```

then in the main `title` template apply templates to `../subtitle` (i.e. navigate from the `title` element to the corresponding `subtitle`)

```
<TitleText><xsl:value-of select="."/></TitleText>
<xsl:apply-templates select="../subtitle" />
```

You don't need the `if` test, as the `apply-templates` will do nothing if its `select` doesn't find any matching nodes.

You will also need to *exclude* the `subtitle` element when applying templates to the children of the `xml` element, otherwise you will get a second copy of the `Subtitle` output element after the `TitleDetail` as well as the one inside it.  The easiest way is to replace your `match="/"` template with the following `match="/*"` one instead

```
<xsl:template match="/*">
    <Product>
        <xsl:apply-templates select="*[not(self::subtitle)]/>
    </Product>
</xsl:template>
```

If you have similar special handling for other elements in other templates you can add those to the `not()`, i.e. `select="*[not(self::subtitle | self::somethingelse)]"`.

Alternatively you could make use of template *modes*

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="ISO-8859-1"?>
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0"
            xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">

<xsl:template match="/">
    <Product>
        <xsl:apply-templates/>
    </Product>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="title">
    <TitleDetail>
        <TitleType>01</TitleType>
        <TitleElement>
            <TitleElementLevel>01</TitleElementLevel>
            <TitleText><xsl:value-of select="."/></TitleText>
            <xsl:apply-templates select="../subtitle" mode="in-title" />
        </TitleElement>
    </TitleDetail>
</xsl:template>

<!-- in "in-title" mode, add a Subtitle element -->
<xsl:template match="subtitle" mode="in-title">
  <Subtitle><xsl:value-of select="."/></Subtitle>
</xsl:template>

<!-- in normal mode, do nothing -->
<xsl:template match="subtitle" />
```

Comment: Thanks for help. I tried your solution, but subtitle tag has been replaced two times: One 'Subtitle' is a descendant of 'TitleDetail' and another is a descendant of 'Product' element. I need only one 'Subtitle' tag inside 'TitleDetail'. P.S. <xsl:apply-templates select="../subtitle" /> - I use this line.

Comment: @Tamara I've added a couple of possible approaches to get around this.

Answer (score 0):

If I understand the question correctly, you can try this:

```
<xsl:if test="following-sibling::subtitle"> 
  <Subtitle>123</Subtitle>
</xsl:if>
```

Comment: Thanks for help. I forgot to mention that subtitle is not necessarily following sibling - it's just sibling.